# How to get text including tags with python webbot?

Tags: python, webbot

I have got this text in a HTML file :

```
<section id="question-a.1" class="level2">
<p>Blabla</p>
<p>if a==b:</p>
<p>c = True</p>
<p>elif a &gt; b+10:</p>
<p>c = True</p>
<p>else:</p>
<p>c = False</p>
</section>
```

But when with Python webbot I try to get this element with :

```
web = Browser()
web.go_to("there")
ques = web.find_elements(id=f"question-a.1")[0].text
```

I got the text alright but without the p tags but I need them. Is there a way to get the entire text within the section tag including the p tags (or any other tag like math, etc.)

Thanks
The

Comment: remove `.text` ?

Comment: In this case I get something like :
`<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="ff12097d7bed03e4bb72e628f3a58d65", element="0.8865863484590528-210")>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the attribute `.get_attribute('outerHTML')` to retrieve the actual html of the selected elements, for example

```
from webbot import Browser
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com')
web.find_elements(id="jhp big")[0].get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

will yield

```
'<a class="gb_Ld gb_od" role="button" tabindex="0" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#4285F4">مراجعة</a>'
```

or you could use `innerHTML` to get the inner html without the wrapping tag

```
web.find_elements(id="fbar")[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

will yield

```
<div class="fbar"><div class="b2hzT"><style data-iml="1585133904756">.b0KoTc{color:rgba(0,0,0,.54);padding-right:27px}.Q8LRLc{font-size:15px}.b0KoTc{margin-right:30px;text-align:right}.b2hzT{border-bottom:1px solid #e4e4e4}</style><div class="b0KoTc"><span class="Q8LRLc">مصر</span></div></div><span id="fsr"><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://policies.google.com/privacy?fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://policies.google.com/privacy%3Ffg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQ8awCCBE">الخصوصية</a><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://policies.google.com/terms?fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://policies.google.com/terms%3Ffg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQ8qwCCBI">البنود</a><span style="display:inline-block;position:relative"><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=ar" id="fsettl" aria-controls="fsett" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="foot.cst" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://www.google.com/preferences%3Fhl%3Dar&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQzq0CCBM">الإعدادات</a><span id="fsett" aria-labelledby="fsettl" role="menu" style="display:none"><a href="https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=ar&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">إعدادات البحث</a><a href="/advanced_search?hl=ar&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">بحث متقدم</a><a href="/history/privacyadvisor/search/unauth?utm_source=googlemenu&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">بياناتك في خدمة "بحث"</a><a href="/history/optout?hl=ar&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">السجلّ</a><a href="//support.google.com/websearch/?p=ws_results_help&amp;hl=ar&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">مساعدة البحث</a><a href="#" data-bucket="websearch" role="menuitem" id="dk2qOd" target="_blank" jsaction="gf.sf" data-ved="0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQLggU">إرسال تعليقات</a></span></span></span><span id="fsl"><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://www.google.com/intl/ar_eg/ads/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpafoot1_1!o2&amp;utm_source=google.com&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=google_hpafooter&amp;fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://www.google.com/intl/ar_eg/ads/%3Fsubid%3Dww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpafoot1_1!o2%26utm_source%3Dgoogle.com%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dgoogle_hpafooter%26fg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQkdQCCBU">الإعلانات</a><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://www.google.com/services/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpbfoot1_1!o2&amp;utm_source=google.com&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=google_hpbfooter&amp;fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://www.google.com/services/%3Fsubid%3Dww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpbfoot1_1!o2%26utm_source%3Dgoogle.com%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dgoogle_hpbfooter%26fg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQktQCCBY">الأعمال</a><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://about.google/?utm_source=google-EG&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=hp-footer&amp;fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://about.google/%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle-EG%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dhp-footer%26fg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQkNQCCBc">حول</a><a class="Fx4vi" href="//google.com/search/howsearchworks/?fg=1">  آلية عمل "بحث Google" </a></span></div>
```

versus `outerHTML` will yeild

```
<div class="EvHmz hRvfYe" id="fbar"><div class="fbar"><div class="b2hzT"><style data-iml="1585133904756">.b0KoTc{color:rgba(0,0,0,.54);padding-right:27px}.Q8LRLc{font-size:15px}.b0KoTc{margin-right:30px;text-align:right}.b2hzT{border-bottom:1px solid #e4e4e4}</style><div class="b0KoTc"><span class="Q8LRLc">مصر</span></div></div><span id="fsr"><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://policies.google.com/privacy?fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://policies.google.com/privacy%3Ffg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQ8awCCBE">الخصوصية</a><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://policies.google.com/terms?fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://policies.google.com/terms%3Ffg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQ8qwCCBI">البنود</a><span style="display:inline-block;position:relative"><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=ar" id="fsettl" aria-controls="fsett" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" jsaction="foot.cst" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://www.google.com/preferences%3Fhl%3Dar&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQzq0CCBM">الإعدادات</a><span id="fsett" aria-labelledby="fsettl" role="menu" style="display:none"><a href="https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=ar&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">إعدادات البحث</a><a href="/advanced_search?hl=ar&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">بحث متقدم</a><a href="/history/privacyadvisor/search/unauth?utm_source=googlemenu&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">بياناتك في خدمة "بحث"</a><a href="/history/optout?hl=ar&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">السجلّ</a><a href="//support.google.com/websearch/?p=ws_results_help&amp;hl=ar&amp;fg=1" role="menuitem">مساعدة البحث</a><a href="#" data-bucket="websearch" role="menuitem" id="dk2qOd" target="_blank" jsaction="gf.sf" data-ved="0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQLggU">إرسال تعليقات</a></span></span></span><span id="fsl"><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://www.google.com/intl/ar_eg/ads/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpafoot1_1!o2&amp;utm_source=google.com&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=google_hpafooter&amp;fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://www.google.com/intl/ar_eg/ads/%3Fsubid%3Dww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpafoot1_1!o2%26utm_source%3Dgoogle.com%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dgoogle_hpafooter%26fg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQkdQCCBU">الإعلانات</a><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://www.google.com/services/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpbfoot1_1!o2&amp;utm_source=google.com&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=google_hpbfooter&amp;fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://www.google.com/services/%3Fsubid%3Dww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpbfoot1_1!o2%26utm_source%3Dgoogle.com%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dgoogle_hpbfooter%26fg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQktQCCBY">الأعمال</a><a class="Fx4vi" href="https://about.google/?utm_source=google-EG&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=hp-footer&amp;fg=1" ping="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;source=webhp&amp;url=https://about.google/%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle-EG%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_campaign%3Dhp-footer%26fg%3D1&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiOvK76u7XoAhVEEncKHf5pA1YQkNQCCBc">حول</a><a class="Fx4vi" href="//google.com/search/howsearchworks/?fg=1">  آلية عمل "بحث Google" </a></span></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I still need to get rid of the <section...> and </section> tags. I can do some regexp. No magical function otherwise ?

Comment: I'm not sure such function exits out of the box from ```web element```, but sure there are a couple of post-processing tricks to handle this, you could even use beautiful soup parse trees to remove the parent or  just handle it with a regex.

Comment: I think ```innerHTML```  could do that too, maybe you could give it a try first to save you extra effort for building customized regex for each tag